# How strong/vulgar is using "to bitch" in the meaning of "to complain"?

Tags: offensive-language

I understand that calling a woman *a bitch* is a very strong language. However, is the word vulgar *per se*? Specifically, when used as a verb *to bitch* in the meaning of *to complain* (see [What's the meaning of "bitching"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/64911/73094)), is it also so strong? Could you use it in front of your grandmother? :)

ADDED: Is it acceptable to use it towards kids?

As a parent:

> Stop bitching about the food.

As a teacher:

> If you keep bitching about the homework, I'll give you even more.

As a bonus, could you place here some *examples* of *to bitch* in the above mentioned meaning so the wider context (such as prepositions which may follow etc.) is made apparent?

Comment: You don't know what "vulgar" means (check dictionary).  Vulgar means **lower-class**.  Nothing could be more lower-class than using "bitch".  It is utterly inconceivable in English that a parent would use the word "bitch" in talking to children.  try to understand that in many ways ***it is EVEN MORE TABOO IN ENGLISH that swear-words such as "cunt" or "fuck"***.  It's in the same category as using "n___er" or "sl___-eye" to refer to racial groups.  The word "bitch" *must not* come out of your mouth.

Comment: @JoeBlow: *to bitch* and *the bitch* probably differ in strength.

Comment: @JoeBlow: According to Merriam-Webster, *vulgar* has several meanings: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vulgar. I mean the number 5: " offensive in language, lewdly or profanely indecent". I have seen/heard *bitching about something* in many American movies, and it was not a matter of *class*. And you probably are aware that the offensive language is not felt taboo for non-native speakers, as we lack the "instinct" which you native ones learned throughout your childhood.

Comment: Set aside the meaning of vulgar.  So, there are swear words (such as cunt or fuck).  But *even worse*, there are racial and group slurs.  **You have probably heard n _ _ _ _ er and sl _ _ _ -eye and f _ _ _ ot many times in movies, am I right?**  Allow me to explain again, ***worse*** than swear words are racial/group slurs. Is it making sense?  (1) you hear these racial/group slurs in (bad) movies quite often - right?  OK we're clear on that!  (2) I would urge you to never have the word you ask about, come from your mouth, you know?  Same with the other three I mention herein. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somewhat vulgar and I wouldn't use it in front of my grandmother.

Anything you can follow 'talk' with, you can follow 'bitch' (in the verb sense) with:

> That guy is always bitching about his job
>
> Don't come bitching to me about your job

And so on...

In reference to your edit:

A teacher certainly wouldn't use it, and neither would a responsible parent (of younger children - teenagers *perhaps*). While it's relatively mild, it is still something of an expletive.

In short, you wouldn't use it in *any* polite conversation. You would only use it a situation where you would otherwise be comfortable cursing/swearing.

Comment: "somewhat vulgar" - so is it *(much) less* vulgar than *a bitch* about a woman?

Comment: Well, yes, mainly because it's not pejorative - it's not a direct insult.

Comment: Is it *not* pejorative??? I have understood that using *to bitch* about someone complaining is *always* pejorative! By saying that about someone I express my disgust from his behaviour.

Comment: Well, maybe a little, but not as pejorative as actually calling someone _a bitch_.

Comment: I would change the last part to "comfortable with **mild** cursing/swearing." I definitely know a lot of people (including myself) who would, in certain contexts, use *bitching* but would balk at stronger curses such as *fuck*, *shit*, or *cunt*. To put it another way, saying someone is *"bitching"* would be used in the same contexts where you might also use the word *bitch* as a noun. (The exception being that the noun is sometimes seen as misogynistic.)

Comment: I think it's pejorative in the sense that it suggests you disapprove. "He complains about his job" (and I agree with him); "he bitches about his job" (and I probably dislike his bitchiness, except perhaps if I'm a bitch myself).

Answer (score 3):

I am a native New Yorker (from Harlem) living in Brazil, and am having some difficulty explaining to my English students the subtle mutations through which English word meanings pass.
Because of the pervasive nature and influence of hip hop language in modern American youth culture, "Bitch" as meaning a vulgar woman, a whore, a "loose" woman, etc, has been replaced by the word "Hoe". Bitch has been relegated to the meaning of a person who is difficult to get along with, in the sense that they complain incessantly. Of course the context in which it is used gives the intended meaning, but for the most part the long-standing verbal meaning has also become the nominal meaning. "She's a bitch" now means that she "bitches" too much, or complains too much. In it's usage to refer to males, it means that he is a coward. I am now waiting for online dictionaries (except for the Urban Dictionary which already reflects this) to conform to this reality.

To directly answer the question, ALL perjorative words like this are both strong and vulgar. It is ALWAYS advisable to apply suitable non-offensive words (and you can ALWAYS find them), unless you have been offended first and have no recourse - For there continue to be people who only understand and respond to this type of discourse...

Answer (score 2):

Neither of *my* grandmothers would have used the word "bitch" except in relation to dog breeding, and perhaps not even there. That said, I know many grandmothers who regularly use the word, and who do not object when the word is used in their presence,  that it's safe to say that the status of the word is in transition, and it is considerably less vulgar than it once was. It is frequently used as an alternative for "complain", and takes pretty much the same prepositions and other usage as that word. Further complicating usage is that in some subcultures, "bitchin" is used as an adjective that I understand has favorable characteristics.

That said, I generally refrain from using the word, because over use of the word is obscuring its meaning and impact.

Comment: Brasshat:  Your last sentence makes an excellent point:   "bitch" should be rarely used but profoundly meant.  If it becomes neutral, what (probably horrible) word will replace it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not something my grandmothers say. Some parents may use it, but it is still definitely vulgar.

But I think it's definitely misogynistic, both the noun and the verb. The noun is specific to women. The verb implies that acting in a certain type of specifically female way is wrong/annoying. Just think about if you substituted a different pejorative term for a different group of people:

"Stop complaining about the homework" ->
"Stop bitching about the homework" ->
"Stop n*****-ing about the homework" ->
"Stop sp$cing about the homework"->
"Stop f*ggoting about the homework"

Now, none of those are actual verbs. But if they were, and you heard it, wouldn't you find it offensive?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, saying *to bitch* is far less offensive than using *bitch* as a slur, but it certainly isn’t polite. I’d be interested to know where those who say the word is among the worst are from. I’ve never known an English-speaking culture that considers *bitch* worse than *cunt* or *fuck.*

*Bitch* is considered a fairly strong word, but *bitching* is generally considered among the mildest possible swear words, to the point that there are plenty of people who would not consider it swearing.